# What happens when you give a null string to a C standard function?

Tags: c, string, null, std

There are many endearing string functions in the C standard library, such as (in `string.h`)

```
char *strcat(char *str1, const char *str2);
```

or (in `stdlib.h`)

```
long int strtol(const char *nptr, char **endptr, int base);
```

(Ignore the wisdom of calling these functions, for the purposes of this question.)

What will happen if I pass any of these functions a `NULL` pointer?  (I mean `(char *) 0`, not the empty string.)

I haven't found any answers in the man pages or on the web.

This leads me to think it's implementation-defined, but it could just as well mean an automatic segmentation fault; no special error behavior or return values are specified, either.

Could the behavior even vary from function to function, within the same implementation?

Comment: Hmmm... there are 5 answers now: 3 undefined, 2 implementation-dependent. At least some of them are wrong!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The C standard says it in **7.21.1 String Function Conventions, clause 2**:

> Unless explicitly stated otherwise in the description of a particular
>   function in this subclause, pointer arguments on such a call shall
>   still have valid values, as described in 7.1.4.

**7.1.4 Use of library functions**:

> If an argument to a function has an invalid value (such as a value
>   outside the domain of the function, or a pointer outside the address
>   space of the program, or a null pointer, or a pointer to
>   non-modifiable storage when the corresponding parameter is not
>   const-qualified) or a type (after promotion) not expected by a
>   function with variable number of arguments, the behavior is undefined.

`strcat()`'s description in **7.21.3.1** says nothing about the NULL pointer being a valid input, hence, I conclude, the behavior is officially undefined if any of its input pointers is NULL.

Comment: Is there a link to this?  Or to something similar but also authoritative?

Comment: [Final version of the C99 standard with corrigenda TC1, TC2, and TC3 included, formatted as a draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) -- link taken from Wikipedia. Apparently, there's some work in progress and there're newer drafts as well, e.g. n1548.

Comment: Thanks! I should note that the first quotation from the standard talks about the case where the length supplied is 0: even if you plan to (e.g.) copy 0 characters, the pointers are expected to be valid.

Answer (score 2):

The standard doesn't say anything, so it's undefined behaviour.  On many platforms, you'll get a seg-fault, because it will be dereferencing a null pointer.

Answer (score 2):

Unless it's specified what the function does with NULL values (for example `endptr` being NULL is defined), then the result in undefined - crash, error code, abort, or demons out of your nose.

Answer (score 0):

The C specification doesn't mention what will happen if you pass erroneous arguments to e.g. `strcat` and similar functions, so it's entirely implementation dependent. But I would bet not many implementations check for `NULL` parameters in release builds at least.

Comment: Alex brought the example from the standard, so it's not implementation dependent; it's undefined.

Answer (score 0):

It will be implementation depended. But you will be getting segfaults on many implementations. coz since the string function is extensively used, these library function usually dosent do the nullcheck. (must be because for efficiency)

EDIT : As @Alex mentioned it's not implementation dependent; it's undefined.

Comment: It's not implementation dependent; it's undefined.  I wouldn't be surprised at all about the segfaults.